# How to find file extensions as any number in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to find extension of files with any number, could you please help.

/dp.104, /dp.102, /dp.101, /dp.103

output required for below

```
    `find <Path>/log -type f -name "dp.[0-9]+" `
```

Regards,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

With *find*'s `-regex` option:

```
find /path -type f -regex '.*/dp\.[0-9]+'
```